# Error: time data doesn't match format specified, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I need to convert a numpy array of strings into datetime format. Apparently I am not specifying the format correctly, but I don't see how.

```
import pandas as pd

temp_datetime = pd.to_datetime(temp_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

where temp_time is {ndarray:(11368,)} with contents in this format: "2023-04-05 13:42:55.355"

Gives this error:

ValueError: time data "2023-04-05 13:42:55.355" doesn't match format specified

Comment: According to [this table](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units) you are not using the right format, for example you are inverting months and minutes.

Comment: @Raida Really? Ew. That's incompatible with what `datetime.strptime` uses.

Comment: You could try the use the format from the table to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I use that format, I get the error 'D' is a bad directive (and when I decapitalise D, it gives the same error for 'h' and then 's', and after I recapitalise those I get the same error as in the OP)

Comment: Actually the error differs slightly when I use m for minutes and M for months and the other way round:
ValueError: time data "2023-04-05 13:42:55.355" doesn't match format specified
ValueError: time data '"2023-04-05 13:42:55.355"' does not match format '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S.%f' (match)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Which pandas version are you using? Also, isn't this the standard format? It should work even without specifying the `format` argument. You could also try `format="ISO8601"`.